# Programming a drone to flight indoor using opencv

Tags: opencv

I am newbie with drones. I would like to develop a program to manage a drone using `opencv` to fly indoor over a line.

I am searching a lot of languages but most all of them are GPS based. I saw there is an alternative which calls `SLAM` to detect the position using the sensors. 
Well I have a line in the floor and a camera on my drone. I like mission planner but I am not quite sure if it is the best choice. I will be using **Parrot AR**, but I would like to use any drone. 
So I would like to use mission planner but I am not sure if it is the best choice.

What would be the best SDK you would recommend me to use in order to manage the drone not using the GPS points but relative locations or `SLAM`?

Comment: i do not know where to start. I will appreciate anyone who help me instad of voting down

Comment: This is why you're getting downvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This is where your 2 minute google search should have lead you, http://vision.in.tum.de/data/software/tum_ardrone ,

Comment: As I said.. I have already seen this page, thanks. So, do you recommend me this, over node-ar-drone, mission planner, 3dr, jdi... and all the existing sdks ? I said "I am seaching a lot of languages".. and asked for a recommendation of the best approach. I spent a week searching, not just 2 minutes. So Why you think it is the best?

Comment: If you want I can make a list of all the sdks I've seen.. as I said, I do not know where to start. But there are a lot of geniuses which like voting down instead of helping, and like judjing the effort of a newbie have made.

Comment: By the way, if you don't like my question, just 1 negative vote would be ok.. and the link : stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you think it is not the way to ask (I think it is). Feel free to ignore my question.

Comment: @GabrielBursztyn - I think you have a very legitimate question here. I too have scoured google to see where to start. And I too would like to know how to move a drone programmatically. Have you found any answers/insights since your original post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have the Parrot API ,and a couple of wrappers in different languages. [Node-AreDrone](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone) for `nodeJs`, [PyArdrone](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone) for `python`, and there is a wrapper coded in C# which I have used [AR.Drone](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/AR.Drone). It has a good user interface which you can see the both cameras, record and replay the videos, control the drone by clicking on buttons, you can see the metrics and configuration of the drone and you have also a way to send commands in a queue. Because I love c# and the features I've mentioned you have already in a user interface, I prefer this. Most of them are quite the same as they use the Parrot API inside by sending udp messages. I couldn't try others, so, there are a lot, and anybody could tell me which one is the best. For [mission planner](http://ardupilot.org/planner/index.html) I couldn't find a good solution for indoors. So, for anyone who is lost and do not know here to start as I was. I recommend to select the language you want and search for the corresponding wrapper. If you like c# as me, so `AR.Drone` is a good choice.
Also if you want to do something with OpenCV. [Copterface](https://github.com/paulhayes/copterface) is a good example. You could implement it in any language with OpenCV.

Comment: I see alot of sdk's have ways to control the drone (ex: buttons from a UI). But i was wondering if there is any way to program (in C#) a drone so that it can fly/move and do some actions (take photos) in an autonomous way.